# How to avoid MediaPlayer's starting black screen?

Tags: android, media-player

So in my app MediaPlayer is based on SurfaceView by extending like:

```
public class VideoView extends SurfaceView  {}
```

now, it uses MediaPlayer inside and what I want to achieve is to make starting color of screen white instead of black. VideoView is placed in white-backgrounded-layout by itself. It is white but atm it starts playing video the VideoView becomes black for a second. Video by itself has white background and its first frames are not black so I assume that its about MediaPlayer. When it starts playing it turns screen black by default. I had guessed that I could use transition like:

```
TransitionDrawable transition = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE), new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)});

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(transition);
else
    this.setBackground(transition);

transition.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
transition.startTransition(1000);
```

However this doesn't help much. So is there a way to achieve my goal?
Forgot to mention that its local video file (from SD card) is being played. So black screen is not about a long HTTP-session establishing or other stream related things. And preparation is done via `prepareAsync();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a nasty solution finally. Oh well its better than nothing:

```
private TransitionDrawable transition;
private Animation videoViewFadeInAnimation;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void start() {

    if (videoViewFadeInAnimation == null){
        videoViewFadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        videoViewFadeInAnimation.setDuration(600);
        videoViewFadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        videoViewFadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                if (DeviceInfo.hasAPI11())
                    setAlpha(1);
            }
        });

    }

    if (transition == null){
        transition = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE), new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)});
        transition.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);

        if(DeviceInfo.hasAPI16())
            this.setBackground(transition);
        else
            this.setBackgroundDrawable(transition);
    }

    if (isInPlaybackState()) {
        if (mCurrentState!=STATE_PAUSED){
            startAnimation(videoViewFadeInAnimation);
            transition.startTransition(1);
        }
        hideVideoControls();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYING;
    }
    mTargetState = STATE_PLAYING;
}
```

its a method of my VideoView which starts video playing. Basically it makes 0 alpha for VideoView and a white bg for 1ms (doesn't work without bg transition) and then animates alpha from 0 to 1 for 600ms. If use value lt 600 then the annoying black screen becomes noticeable. However 600ms of no video visible also not the best thing cuz visually audio starts earlier. This solutions doesn't work always and don't know why.